# Jasmine + test an inherited method has been called

Tags: inheritance, jasmine

Whats the best way to test with Jasmine that an inherited method has been called?

I am only interested in testing whether or not it has been called as I have unit tests set up for the base class.

example is:

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {


    function ObjectOne () {

    }

    ObjectOne.prototype.methodOne = function ()  {
        console.log("parent method");
    }


    function ObjectTwo () {
        ObjectTwo.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Y.extend(ObjectTwo, ObjectOne);

    ObjectTwo.prototype.methodOne = function () {
        console.log("child method");

        ObjectTwo.superclass.methodOne.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})
```

I want to test that ObjectTwo's inherited methodOne has been called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you can spy the method in the prototype of `ObjectOne`.

```
spyOn(ObjectOne.prototype, "methodOne").andCallThrough();
obj.methodOne();
expect(ObjectOne.prototype.methodOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The only caveat of this method is that it won't check if `methodOne` was called on the `obj` object. If you need to make sure it was called on `obj` object, you can do this :

```
var obj = new ObjectTwo();
var callCount = 0;

// We add a spy to check the "this" value of the call.    //
// This is the only way to know if it was called on "obj" //
spyOn(ObjectOne.prototype, "methodOne").andCallFake(function () {
    if (this == obj)
        callCount++;

    // We call the function we are spying once we are done //
    ObjectOne.prototype.methodOne.originalValue.apply(this, arguments);
});

// This will increment the callCount. //
obj.methodOne();
expect(callCount).toBe(1);    

// This won't increment the callCount since "this" will be equal to "obj2". //
var obj2 = new ObjectTwo();
obj2.methodOne();
expect(callCount).toBe(1);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it let the spy on the ObjectOne.prototype.methodOne after the test being executed ? I'm concerned that could cause trouble for other tests using this method. Especially for the second exemple with .andCallFake()

Comment: @challet This shouldn't be an issue. All spies are cleared after each test.